# Transferring 10K+ from one bank to another bank domestically

Tags: united-states, irs, money-transfer

I would like to transfer some money from my checking account at Bank of America to my savings account at Wells Fargo. The $ amount exceeds 20K. I wonder if this will be a problem in terms of IRS. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the IRS doesn't care about your transfers.